# How to add phonegap plugin without cli?

Tags: android, cordova, admob, phonegap-build, cordova-plugins

I created Phonegap project for android platform using Phonegap desktop app. Which allows basic file structuring. I edit that files as my requirement. Due to some uncertain reasons I can't Install cordova/phonegap On my PC using cli.Now I want Install/add plugin in my project. How can I do so ? I mean how can I add plugin manually
I want to add cordova-plugin-admob.

Comment: cordova plugin install <path of pulgin incase on locaal machine OR plugin-name>

Comment: Don't do that. The way is difficult and depends of the plugin. Try to fix your installation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of cordova-admob plugin (https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova). As Joerg said, this is very difficult and may be easier to try to fix phonegap cli.

That said, there is nothing impossible :)

- Download the plugin from https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova/archive/master.zip and uncompress it (or `git clone https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova.git cordova-admob`)
- Copy all java files from `cordova-admob/src/android/*.java` in `yourProjectFolder/src/com/admob/appfeel/cordova/admob/`
- Copy all js files from `cordova-admob/www/*.js` in `yourProjectFolder/assets/www/plugins/cordova-admob/www/*.js`
- Download the plugin from https://github.com/appfeel/connectivity-monitor-cordova/archive/master.zip and uncompress it (or `git clone https://github.com/appfeel/connectivity-monitor-cordova.git connectivity-monitor-cordova`)
- Copy all java files from `connectivity-monitor-cordova/src/android/*.java` in `yourProjectFolder/src/com/admob/appfeel/cordova/connectivity/`
- Copy all js files from `connectivity-monitor-cordova/www/*.js` in `yourProjectFolder/assets/www/plugins/cordova-connectivity-monitor/www/*.js`
- Modify cordova_plugins.js. It should look similar to this (other plugins may be present):

  ```
  cordova.define('cordova/plugin_list', function(require, exports, module) {
  module.exports = [
      {
          "file": "plugins/cordova-admob/www/admob.js",
          "id": "cordova-admob.AdMobAds",
          "clobbers": [
              "window.admob",
              "window.tappx"
          ]
      },
      {
          "file": "plugins/cordova-connectivity-monitor/www/connectivity.js",
          "id": "cordova-connectivity-monitor.connectivity",
          "clobbers": [
              "window.connectivity"
          ]
      }
  ];
  module.exports.metadata = 
  {
      "cordova-admob": "4.1.6",
      "cordova-connectivity-monitor": "1.2.2",
  }
  });
  ```
- Ensure your project has `google-play-services_lib` referenced (see https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)
- In your app's manifest add the following tags as a child of the  element:

  ```
   <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
   <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
  ```
- Also ensure that the following permissions are granted:

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  ```

With all that changes done, you should be able to use the plugin in your app as described in https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova

Good luck!